# How can I calculate the score of buyers and randomly select one using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, random

I have asked a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/299577/what-is-a-readable-algorithm-for-selecting-a-random-buyer-based-on-what-they-pur/299596#299596) before, but the answers were not exact, due to my problem not being clear enough. I did accept the answer because it fit my question, but I'm still not sure of the next step, so here is me, trying again.

I am working on a lottery system, which is, I've heard, based on [fitness proportionate selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection). I am not good enough with algorithms to be certain though, so I am going to describe the selection criteria anyway.

I am selling two products. Buying product number 1 gives the buyer 10 tickets in the lottery, and buying product number 2 gives them 15 tickets. At the end, all tickets are put together into a metaphoric bucket, and a buyer is randomly drawn. Having more tickets *does* improve your chances, but doesn't guarantee being chosen.

In my programming language (PHP), I have an array that has the points for each product, like this:

```
[
    1 => 10,
    2 => 15
]
```

Now, taking into account that the product weights are not stored into the database, what is the query to select one (or more) random buyers, taking their fitness (i.e. the number of tickets they've earned) into account?
I'm not good with algorithms, so I'd also appreciate it if your answer would include information for an algorithms beginner.

### Update: why am I not doing this in PHP?

The problem I have with doing this in PHP is that the number of data is huge. In one week, I have 800000 sales. Loading all of this into the memory in an array makes me go over the 130 MB limit, and I prefer my application not to take so much memory. Of course, if there is no other way, I will do this as suggested in the comments, but I just want to make sure, through this question, that there is no better way to achieve this.

Comment: Is there a reason your products do not have a corresponding database table with the score? Is there are reason you cannot solve this in PHP code?

Comment: I would not do this in sql, since you do not have the weights available for any query. I would assign each buyer a range of numbers based on the number of tickets. So, if buyer 1 has 10 tickets, and buyer 2 has 20, then buyer 1 would get range of 1 to 10, buyer 2 range 11 to 30. Then I would generate a random number between 1 and 30. If the generated number falls into the range of 1 to 10, then the 1st buyer wins, otherwise, the 2nd.

Comment: My problem is that the number of records is 800000. That is, I have 800000 sales in each period, and creating an array with 800000 elements requires a lot of memory. I'm looking for a way to not run out of memory in my PHP application.

Comment: Is it a lottery, or a raffle?

Comment: Honestly? It seems like neither. There is no jackpot, and the prise is a giveaway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this in your application code instead of the database, but in two steps to save memory.

Step 1: Calculate the sum of the number of lottery tickets sold. Do this by making an SQL query for all sales, ordered by time or id. Loop over the result, one row at a time. While doing so, keep a counter of the number of tickets sold (for each row you increase the counter based on the product, so increase by 10 for product 1, 15 for product 2 etc).

Step 2: Find the winner. Generate a random number between 1 and your counter value. Save this random number to a variable. Do the same SQL query, sorted by the same column. This time, decrease the variable's value by the number of tickets. When the variable is equal to or below 0 you have found your winner! Break out of the loop and do whatever you need to do with the winner.

Something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT customer_id, product_id FROM purchases ORDER BY sold_at';
$counter = 0;
foreach ($db->query($query) as $row) {
  $tickets = $products_to_tickets[$row['product_id']];
  $counter += $tickets;
}

$new_counter = mt_rand(1, $counter);
foreach ($db->query($query) as $row) {
  $tickets = $products_to_tickets[$row['product_id']];
  $new_counter -= $tickets;
  if ($new_counter <= 0) {
    $winner = $row['customer_id'];
    break;
  }
}
// $winner is now the winning customer id!
```

This solution will require very little PHP memory since you only ever have one row and a few variables in memory.